# AWT paint tools not pixel perfect

Tags: java, eclipse, awt

When using the AWT package to draw stuff I've found that sometimes when I'm using functions such as fillRect or copyArea, it will sometimes add a pixel to the side or bottom, and is getting quite annoying and noticable when painting very small shapes.

How do I fix this?

Update: Here's a picture of what happens when I do `g.fillRect(1, 1, 3, 3);`, which should produce a 3 by 3 rectangle:
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vl9XV.png)

It is hard to see but there is a row of pixels added to the right side.

Comment: If we can't see your problem with our own eyes, we are not able to help you. Consider creating a [mcve] and adding some kind of an image that shows the problem. We can't start making assumptions hoping to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the documentation for [`fillRect()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#fillRect(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)), and note that the coordinates are treated differently from `drawRect()`. `fillRect()` fills in a rectangle that's 1 pixels wider and taller than `drawRect()`.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this is the issue. I'm sorry that I didn't make it clear in my question, but it only happens sometimes, depending on where the rectangle is. For example, doing ```g.fillRect(3, 5, 3, 3);```  produces a perfect 3 by 3 rectangle, even though it is the same dimensions of the rectangle shown in the question, which comes out as a 4 by 3 rectangle.